Access to XMLHttpRequest at ' from origin ' has been blocked by CORS policy only on Azure published .net core application
I know there are many similar questions on this exact same issue but why I am posting it again is because I have tried all the solutions already and also I am facing this problem in a particular environment only.
I have my .Net 6 website where I enable cors like this
Console.WriteLine(configuration["App:BaseAppPath"]); // this is picking correct value
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins(configuration["App:BaseAppPath"])
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
});

And this works perfectly fine on my local environment but it starts breaking when I deployed it on Azure VM. It always give this error
One of the suggestions was to add the cors policy in web.config of the deployed version, so I added this also to the web.config of my deployed project
<cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="false">
    <add origin="<My Origin>" allowed="true" />
</cors>

But that too is not working.
I do not know where there is something specific that I have to do for azure or the deployed version but nothing seems to working so far.
Any leads of what should I try?
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'XXXX' from origin 'http://mydomain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


I don't know what configuration["App:BaseAppPath"] expands to, but I suspect it's not a valid Web origin. If it isn't, you need to fix that.

I also find other users facing the same issue when using AddDefaultPolicy, will check it later. I recommend you to use below way to fix the cors issue.

Do you still meet this cors issue? If so, could you please share more detailed information, I am looking forward to seeing your message.

@JasonPan - I finally fixed it. I fixed it by modfying the web.config cors policy section, turned out that more checks were required their. I will share the solution next week as I am on holiday currently. Also, App:BasePath is resolving an absolutely correct value, I specifically mentioned that in my question, so it is definitely not an invalid origin problem. About problem with AddDefaultPolicy, I am not sure if that could be the reason because I am still using it and it works, looks like mine one is totally working from web.config setting so basically I do not care about it now.

@PawanNogariya - Are you back from holiday?  What did you change to web.config?

Tips 1. After testing, we can't use WithOrigins() and AllowAnyOrigin() together.
Tips 2. The url inside the WithOrigins() should be https://url.com, can't contains /, like https://url.com/.
Try to use AddPolicy to enable the CORS feature.
//Allow All
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyMethod()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials();
}));

// Allow some specific sites
//builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
//{
//    policy
//        .WithOrigins(configuration["App:BaseAppPath"]) 
//        .AllowAnyMethod()
//        .AllowAnyHeader()
//        .AllowCredentials();
//}));
...
app.UseRouting();
// the order is very important
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.UseAuthorization();

...

Because asp.net core is cross-platform, I recommend implementing CORS from the code level, so that you need to migrate to Linux Server in the future without additional configuration.

Your suggestion about trying to make it work from code rather than web.config considering the code can be deployed on Linux and then new configuration would be required for Linux again makes quite sense. I will definitely try your solution and will let you know. About AllowAnyOrigin, I am guessing I left that line by mistake because I was trying different things and I think that line was left by mistake there along with WithOrigins. Will update you one I am back home and try. Thank you very much for the answer and the explanation
